# How do I push an element into an array within an object in MongoDB database?

Tags: python, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm new to MongoDB and I'm trying to figure out how to push an element into an array inside of an object. Here is the database:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "605cee2f08588cb6263c33a4"
    },
    "userID": "9346",
    "firstName": "James",
    "sessionsLog": {
        "date": [],
        "timestamp": [],
        "duration": []
    }
},
    {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "605cee825ef711180adbc141"
    },
    "userID": "4778",
    "firstName": "Rob",
    "sessionsLog": {
        "date": [],
        "timestamp": [],
        "duration": []
    }
}
```

I have a date that I want to push into Rob's 'date' array: 3/30/2021.

What is the operation to push this new date into the date array?

This is what I've tried:

```
import pymongo
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("...")
mydb= myclient["myDatabase"]
users = mydb["Users"]

userID = '4778'
dateToPush = '3/30/2021'
allUsers = users.find({}, {'_id': 1, 'userID': 1, 'sessionsLog': 1})
for u in allUsers:
    if u.get('userID') == userID:
        users.update_one(
            {'userID': u.get('userID')},
            {'$push': {'sessionsLog'['date']: dateToPush}}
        )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/

Use `.` for nested objects in your query.

Change

```
'$push': {'sessionsLog'['date']: dateToPush}
```

to

```
'$push': {'sessionsLog.date': dateToPush}
```

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/30GIvWkHDV1

```
db.collection.update({
  "userID": "9346"
},
{
  $push: {
    "sessionsLog.date": { a: 1, b: 2 }
  }
})
```

Comment: It is also probably better to have a single array with log entries instead of 3 arrays for the 3 fields.

Comment: Works perfectly, exactly what I needed thank you.